# PHP and Javascript sha256 value not matching

Tags: php, node.js, sha256, cryptojs, hmac

##### PHP

```
$apiKey='1DxhT7xiQPcliOnWLO/IOf74VqwxCCohJAhf8AE4TzmyAUqPawKEOQOKBMEu3Cqnbm1DJTbNje//J8W4QqU83Zg==';
$hashValue=(hash_hmac(
    'sha256', 
    'orgID=6197bf9239fef3001b9241c2&userIdentifier=2717&isCorporate=true',
    utf8_decode($apiKey)
));
//Value is : 787a88e590659ea889a8081b35043a9a5fb092af7e69736920c96109dc511182
```

##### JS

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const secret = 'DxhT7xiQPcliOnWLO/IOf74VqwxCCohJAhf8AE4TzmyAUqPawKEOQOKBMEu3Cqnbm1DJTbNje//J8W4QqU83Zg==';
const hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
    'orgID=6197bf9239fef3001b9241c2&userIdentifier=2717&isCorporate=true', 
    secret
);
const hash = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex); //_HMAC_Hash_asHex_

console.log(hash);

//Value is : 2f577ba975be5f76df586f5536bf9c0ae8328a90de2a60d8be8bef29aea5f4c5
```

Comment: Your `$apiKey` and `secret` value is not matched.

Comment: Your `$apiKey` doesn't match `secret`: `$apiKey='1DxhT7...` vs `secret = 'DxhT7...`. Also, `utf8_decode` is entirely pointless there.

Answer (score 0):

Your $apiKey And `const secret` is different. Please check

```
$apiKey='1DxhT7xiQPcliOnWLO/IOf74VqwxCCohJAhf8AE4TzmyAUqPawKEOQOKBMEu3Cqnbm1DJTbNje//J8W4QqU83Zg==';
const secret = 'DxhT7xiQPcliOnWLO/IOf74VqwxCCohJAhf8AE4TzmyAUqPawKEOQOKBMEu3Cqnbm1DJTbNje//J8W4QqU83Zg==';
```